# Chebyshev's Inequality question with variance given

Tags: probability

[image]

I don't gett the solution why it's $\frac {1}{100}$ The solution that I got was P(|x - 50| $\geqslant$ 50) $\leqslant$ $\frac {1}{k^2}$ = $\frac{5}{50^2}$ = $\frac {1}{500}$

what did  I do wrong here?

Comment: $P(|X-50|\geq 50)\leq\frac{5}{50^2}$. The solution may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct and the word "variance" has wrongly been used here.

They probably meant "standard deviation".

Chebyshev says that: $$P(|X-\mu|\geq k\sigma)\leq k^{-2}$$ so in your case: $$P(|X-50|\geq k\sqrt 5)\leq k^{-2}$$ Substituting $k\sqrt5=50$ gives $k^2=500$.

Answer (score 1):

$P(|X-50|\geq 50)\leq\frac{5}{50^2}$.[1] The solution may be incorrect.

A possible error is the solution uses $$P(|X-\mu|\geq n\sigma)\leq\frac{1}{n^2}$$ However, one overlooks that $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

[1] Note that another form of Chebyshev's inequality is $$P(|X-\mu|\geq c)\leq\frac{\sigma^2}{c^2}$$